# Determine whether any of class member can do heap allocation?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, dynamic-memory-allocation, traits

I have encountered the following problem.
Given we have `class Foo`, is there a way (trait/meta-program/trick/...) to determine(compile time) whether any of class **members** can do heap allocations?

Something like this:

```
class A
{
    int a = 5;
    std::array<int,10> arr;
    ...
};

class B
{
    char c;
    std::string s;
    ...
};
```

`can_allocate<A>` yields to false
`can_allocate<B>` yields to true

Potentially `std::string` can allocate if string surpasses small string optimization boundaries.

Is anyone aware of this kind of language feature, or some custom implementation? Or maybe its not even achievable?

Comment: C++ code can't examine itself, so there's just no way to know (inside the program itself) if a function can allocate heap memory. You need other external static analyzers for that. Or external dynamic run-time analyzers, for functions for which you have no source code.

Comment: I was sort of hoping some traits that can do recursive search in members and see anyone has any usage of operator new, operator &, etc.. Not spasticity this but similar

Comment: What is your actual problem that you are trying to solve with this question?

Comment: We need to implement a set of classes that will be written to shared memory. Thus need flat structure/no allocations. So we want to prohibit the potential disaster at compile time.

Comment: Static analysis tools (as I already mentioned), unit-testing, code-reviews. These are really the only way to go.

Comment: Say you have a non-final virtual function. Would you return `true` or `false` for an implementation that you don't see compile-time?

Comment: [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)? It's far more restrictive than what you asked for, but might be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but if you can use c++20 and you can live with some restrictions (i.e. it'll work only for *literal types* you might be able leverage the fact that in c++20 memory allocations are allowed in constexpr context as long as they don't bubble into runtime code. So, maybe you're able to build on something along the following lines:

```
class A
{
    int a = 5;
    std::array<int,10> arr;
};

class B
{
    char c{};
    std::string s{};
};

template<typename T>
consteval T check_me() {
    return {};
}

int main() {

    check_me<A>();
    check_me<B>(); // doesn't compile
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Gvfnrjf56).

It seems that msvc incorrectly does not refuse to compile this, but I think that's a compiler bug (?).

Also, note that this code only checks only the default constructor but not whether an allocation may happen in any member function of `T` or it's members.

Comment: As long as the `std::string` object doesn't actually perform a memory allocation, a call to `check_me` is valid. So it is likely to work with default-construction or as long as the string is small enough to fit in to the small string buffer, depending on how the compile-time part of `std::string` is implemented. That's not a bug. Just unspecified whether or not it will pass.

Comment: @user17732522 You're right. I suspected this, and I even tested it by initializing it with some characters; that still compiled in MSVC so I assumed it to be a bug, but now I tried it again with more characters, and yes, now it works as expected.